# Cannot load ClassDiagram.cd URI formats are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I create a new Class Diagram in my ASP.NET Application C# it gives me an error message that says:

```
(Cannot load 'C:\Users\...\...\App_Code\ClassDiagram.cd': URI formats are not supported)
```

I don't have any classes in my ASP.NET project.

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Add the project structure to the question or a snapshot of it, or instructions regarding how to reproduce - can't do much with so little info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string uri = "file:\\C:\Users\...\...\App_Code\ClassDiagram.cd";
string localPath = new Uri(uri).LocalPath;
```

OR

```
@'C:\Users\...\...\App_Code\ClassDiagram.cd'
```

OR

```
'C:\\Users\\...\\...\\App_Code\\ClassDiagram.cd'
```

uper three way to solution of you problem

Answer (score 0):

Please see my full answer to a related post on stackoverflow for more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391113/cannot-load-classdiagram-cd-on-visual-studio-uri-formats-are-not-supported/28463971#28463971).

Under "WEBSITE", select "Use Visual Studio Development Server..." and then try right clicking on your solution (or App_Code worked for me too) and select "View Class Diagram" again.