# Cannot load ClassDiagram.cd on Visual Studio. "URI formats are not supported"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I try to open a class diagram for my **asp.net webforms** project I get the following error. The Class Diagram (.cd) files get generated but I can't open them.

I do have some classes that use the URI class but i don't really think that could be the issue. Right? Why would a class diagram care about one of my classes using a URI datatype?
[image: CANNOT LOAD URI FORMATS ARE NOT SUPPORTED]

I'm using vb.net Visual Studio 2012 and the project is targeting .net 4.0. I'm aware there is [another question in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639904/cannot-load-classdiagram-cd-uri-formats-are-not-supported) asked about the same issue, however there were no answers posted to it and it's close to a year old. 
Help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you open `ClassDiagram6.cd` in notepad or an XML editor are there any URI-style references in there?

Comment: That is a negative. But i think this is because Visual Studio requires you to save it right after you create it. In other words, it will create the container but you need to save the contents.

Comment: Is the XML particularly long, or could you post it here?  If it's too long, maybe put it in a pastebin or similar and post the link

Comment: It's pretty much an empty xml document. Here's the content 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClassDiagram />

Comment: Brian, did you solve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Sorry Gordon, I gave up on the issue, as far as I know it's still happening. I'll check when i get a chance to work on that project again.

Comment: Three year old post and I just hit this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it in Visual Studio 2012 Professional just now for a website I am working on with my team.

This is not about one of your classes using the URI data type.

My setting under "WEBSITE" in Visual Studio was previously set to "Use IIS Express".  When it is set this way, you can select the alternative option, again under "WEBSITE" which is "Use Visual Studio Development Server".  I'm not certain, but I think this is what the other posters describe above when they say "open web site in file system mode".  When I am not using IIS Express, the class diagram generates, is not blank, and opens fine for viewing in the IDE.

Comment: Just a quick note, even using the IIS Express, the ClassDiagram file is created but there is nothing in it. And I don't believe it was visible until changing host servers.

Answer (score -1):

Please open web site in file system mode (and not in IIS express ) and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

when you load the website, visual studio will tell you that it is already using IIS Express to serve websites do you want to continue using it or not, select no so that you can use visual studio and bot the IIS. my things worked after that